# YII 1 Error and exception handling

Tags: url, yii, error-handling, exception

How to handle CHttpException in yii. If someone enter wrong url then i want to redirect user to a Specific page. I can handle divide by 0 error but unable to handel CHttpException
I write this code in module>component>controller

```
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        Yii::app()->attachEventHandler('onError',array($this,'handleError'));
        Yii::app()->attachEventHandler('onException',array($this,'handleError'));
    }

    public function handleError(CEvent $event)
    {

        if ($event instanceof CExceptionEvent)
        if ($event instanceof CHttpException)
        {
            // some logics
        }
        elseif($event instanceof CErrorEvent)
        {
            $arr[0]=$event->code;
            $arr[1]=$event->message;

            $this->render("application.views.site.error", array('event' => $arr));
        }
        $event->handled = TRUE;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Site Controller :

```
public function actionError()
    {
        $this->layout = "viewsLayout";
        if ($error = Yii::app()->errorHandler->error) {
            if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
                echo $error['message'];
            else
                $this->render('error', $error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sir..! Actually the problem is how to detect a CHttpException?

Comment: Detect exceptions with try{} catch{} statements,